# Aligning the textfield horizontally in ext js

Tags: extjs

I have added one radio group inside my form. According to the enabled radio button one or two text field should appear inside the form i.e. if first radio button is enabled then only one text field should appear and in case of 2nd radio button two text field should appear horizontally. From the below code while enabling the 2nd radio two text fields are collapsing on each other. How can i put those text field side by side?

```
{
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'Type',
            name: 'type',
            items: [{
                boxLabel: 'Single IP',
                inputValue: '1',
                checked: true,
            },{
                boxLabel: 'IP Range',
                inputValue: '2'
            }],
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    fn: rgChange
            }},
            
        },{
            default:'textfield',
            layout:'hbox',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'iplabel',
                fieldLabel:'IP',
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'fromlabel',
                fieldLabel:'From',
                hidden:true,
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                id: 'tolabel',
                fieldLabel: 'To',
                hidden:true,
            }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and also [check out this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3f30).

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        width: 300,
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        name: 'type',
        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Single IP',
            inputValue: '1',
            checked: true,
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'IP Range',
            inputValue: '2'
        }],

        listeners: {
            change: function (radio, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                var container = radio.up('panel').getComponent('fields');
                container.getComponent('iplabel').setHidden(newValue.type != '1');
                container.getComponent('fromlabel').setHidden(newValue.type != '2');
                container.getComponent('tolabel').setHidden(newValue.type != '2');
            },
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'hbox',
        itemId: 'fields',
        items: [{
            itemId: 'iplabel',
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'IP',
        }, {
            itemId: 'fromlabel',
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'From',
            hidden: true,
        }, {
            itemId: 'tolabel',
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'To',
            hidden: true,
        }]
    }]
});
```